# textarea gets cleared on innerhtml insert

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page, where a user can select from a dropdown menu. When they click the option in the dropdown menu, the new section gets inserted into the row.

Here is the dropdown:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu px-2 py-3 ms-sm-n4 ms-n5" aria-labelledby="dropdownTable">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item border-radius-md" id="tx1" href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="displayInputtx1()">tx1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item border-radius-md" id="lj1" href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="displayInputPrelj1()">lj1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item border-radius-md" id="jo1" href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="displayInputjo1()">jo1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item border-radius-md" id="pr1" href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="displayInputpr1()">pr1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item border-radius-md" id="cf1" href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="displayInputcf1()">cf1</a></li>
                      </ul>
```

When I click `tx1` for example, this script runs:

```
             function tx1() {
                var submitbutton = document.getElementById('submitbutton')
                var intro = document.getElementById('tx1') 
                var introNewSection = document.getElementById('tx1-row')
                var uniqueID = ""
                var chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
                var length = 7
                for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) uniqueID += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
                uniqueID = uniqueID
                introNewSection.innerHTML +=  '<div class="col-lg-5 mb-lg-0 mb-4" id=' + uniqueID + '> <div class="card z-index-2"> <div class="card-body p-3" style="margin-top: -20px;"> <h6 class="ms-2 mt-4 mb-0">Intro <a href="#" onclick="javascript:deleteInput(' + uniqueID + ')" style="text-align: right; float: right; margin-right: 12px;"><i class="fa fa-times" style="color: gray;"></i></a></h6> <p class="text-sm ms-2">Section 1</p> <div class="container border-radius-lg"> <div class="row"> <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="intro" placeholder="Enter your current Intro" id="intro" style="height: 100px;" required></textarea> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div>'
                submitbutton.style.display = ''
             }
```

this function inserts a new section into a `div`:

```
<div class="row mt-4" id="tx1-row">
            </div>
```

but users can call on this function multiple times, as they should be able too. The problem is, each time a user clicks on the existing a new `tx1` section, if they had written anything in the `textarea` in the new section, it clears the section of any text, and then adds a new blank section beside it.

I'm not sure why this would be happening. Can anyone provide some more insight and/or help?!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score 0):

```
Use javascript .appendChild function, to add the new node or html element al DOM
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HTML</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <body>
    <div id="mydiv">
    </div>
    <p>
      Click "Append"
    </p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">
      Append
    </button>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {

        // Create an "textarea" node:
        const node = document.createElement("textarea");

        // Create a text node:
        const textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");

        // Append the text node to the "textarea" node:
        node.appendChild(textnode);

        // Append the "textarea" node to the div element:
        document.getElementById("mydiv").appendChild(node);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```